# JavaScript time delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, dom-events, timedelay

I'm a newbie in this department, so I was wondering, can I make a type of if statement with a time delay? Example: if a certain action (maybe a click event) is done within a time period, the time is reset, and if it is not, a function is called.

Comment: Absolutely! You're looking for [**`setTimeout()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), or preferably, a [**callback**](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) from a function's execution.

Comment: See **[`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with an `if` statement, but you can with [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) and [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout).

Here's an example of how you can make a function (a `console.log` statement) run every 2 seconds as long as you don't click the button. Clicking the button resets the timer so that another 2 seconds will need to pass before it begins logging again. You can adapt this to fit whatever actual work you need to happen.

```js
var currentTimeoutId;
function resetTimeout() {
  clearTimeout(currentTimeoutId);
  currentTimeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Too Late!');
    resetTimeout();
  }, 2000);
}

resetTimeout();
document.getElementById('demo').onclick = function() {
  resetTimeout();
};
```

```html
<button id="demo">Click Me Or Else I'll Log Something!</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was experimenting with setTimeout(), but I couldn't figure out how to use it properly. Thx!